# Get RandomPlusMinus in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get a random number either + or -:

But what's wrong here

```
func randomPlusMinus(value:Float) -> Float {
    return value * (arc4random() % 2 ? 1 : -1)
}
```

**Error:** Could not find an overload for '*' that accepts the supplied arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
func randomPlusMinus(value:Float) -> Float {
    let invert: Bool = arc4random_uniform(2) == 1
    return value * (invert ? -1.0 : 1.0)
}
```

I don't think you can say `if 0` or `if 1`. You should be using a boolean value with `if` and  the ternary operator (`cond ? v1 : v2`).

Then there's the Swift numerics thing (which is really annoying, they need to add/implement more convertible protocols in the Std library :/ )

PS - I don't have an interpreter handy, but I will double check later

Comment: You could also just have an `if` statement that conditionally returns `value` or `-value` based on that boolean.

Comment: @JustinJohns yeah I originally had written it that way, but I wanted to make it more clear that it needed to be a `Bool` value in the conditional

Comment: This will crash half the time as arc4random returns a 32-bit unsigned value which won't fit into a signed 32-bit value without overflow. When that overflow happens, it'll crash.  Do the modulo before the cast, or, better yet, use arc4random_uniform

Comment: @David I'm think a Swift `Int` is a 64 bit integer, and it has an initializer which accepts a `u_int32_t` value (the return type from `arc4random()` ), so I think that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: It's only 64-bit on some devices.

Comment: Just look around SO at the number of questions about why arc4random crashes to verify that it is indeed a problem. Particularly for iOS development.

Comment: @David Thanks, updated -- will have to check later if this is valid or if a conversion to `Int` is necessary

Comment: Ohh noo. Something I get an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error

Comment: Your update has an error :arc4random_uniform()  <-- needs a #1 parameter. e.g. arc4random_uniform(10)

Answer (score 1):

Having an explicit test for the result of the modulo operation works for me:

```
func randomPlusMinus(value:Float) -> Float {
    return 0 == (arc4random() % 2) ? value : -value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to answering this, but I feel the simplest solution would be:

```
func randomPlusMinus(value:Float) -> Float {
    return value * (arc4random_uniform(2) * 2 - 1)
}
```

The arc4random call will (supposedly) return 0 50% of the time and 1 50% of the time. So multiplying by 2 gives 0 or 2, then subtracting 1 gives -1 or 1. So the function returns value * -1 50% of the time and value * 1 the other 50% of the time.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are after if you want to random the +- of original value:

```
func randomPlusMinus(value:Float) -> Float {
    let x = arc4random_uniform(2)
    switch x {
    case 0 :
        return value * -1

    default :
        return value
    }
}
```